# Problem on redirection on click in firebase push notification when app is in foreground?

Tags: android

I have just implemented firebase push notification and implemented redirection at click on the notification in both cases when the app is in background and foreground. Just check my code and please give me the solution. If you are getting any code issue then please explain me. Click on notification is working only when the app is in the background its not working when my app is on foreground notification is created in both cases the only redirection does not happen in the foreground case.

```
  public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
            private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
            String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
            PendingIntent pendingIntent;
            private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;
            private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

            private static int getNotificationIcon() {
                return R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
                Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
                Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

                if (remoteMessage.getNotification() == null)
                    return;
                // Check if message contains a notification payload.
                if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                    handleNotification(remoteMessage, remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
                }

            }

            private void handleNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage, String body, String title) {
                if (mNotificationManager == null) {
                    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                }

                boolean isNotificationSound = true;
                //TODO: update count if app is open.
                if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(this)) {
                    if (isNotificationSound) {
                        try {
                            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                            r.play();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                    covertRemoteToJson(remoteMessage, body, title);
                }else {
                    covertRemoteToJson(remoteMessage, body, title);
                }
            }

            private void covertRemoteToJson(RemoteMessage remoteMessage, String body, String title) {
                if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

                    try {
                        //Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
                        if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(remoteMessage.getData().toString())) {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                            handleDataMessage(json, body, title);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        e.getMessage();
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }

            private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json, String body, String title) {
                int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                    assert mNotificationManager != null;
                    NotificationChannel mChannel = mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID);
                    if (mChannel == null) {
                        mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, title, importance);
                        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                    }
                    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.EXTRAS.IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION, true);
                    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.EXTRAS.NOTIFICATION_LANDING_DATA, json.toString());
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
                    builder.setContentTitle(title)                            // required
                            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())   // required
                            .setContentText(body).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()) // required
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                } else {
                    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.EXTRAS.IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION, true);
                    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.EXTRAS.NOTIFICATION_LANDING_DATA, json.toString());
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
                    builder.setContentTitle(title)                            // required
                            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())   // required
                            .setContentText(body).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()) // required
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
                }
                Notification notification = builder.build();
                mNotificationManager.notify(requestID, notification);
            }


        }
```

Comment: What error you are facing, also please format the first part of code also

Comment: @Alok...thanks for reply .now maybe you are getting my code exactly.